# Why don't I see any variables in the Juno workspace?

Tags: julia, atom-editor

I am starting with Julia and Juno. In Juno there is an icon that opens a window called Workspace (not the Julia workspace() command). Supposedly one can see the values of variables in the Workspace. However, the Workspace window is always empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you executing commands inside Juno with shift-enter? Do the results correctly appear to the right of the  input?

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders - I started Atom/Juno, closed the Welcome windows, and got two open windows: Console and Untitled. In neither one of them `Shift+Enter` after a command like `y = 2` has any effect.

Comment: How did you install juno? Which version of Julia?

Comment: @Soldalma Is your issue resolved? I had a similar issue and I have posted my solution down under. Please check me answer if you haven't already and let us know.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders - David, I installed Julia and Atom strictly following the instructions in the Julia website, less than a week ago. That is, I first installed Julia, then Atom, and then the package uber-juno. Here is the link for the instructions: https://github.com/JunoLab/uber-juno/blob/master/setup.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed this problem as well.
Looks like it is a bug with Atom text editor.
It happened to me when the Workspace window was not opened by default upon launching the Atom text editor.

**Solution:**

The Workspace window waits for the run button to be clicked and the file to be saved. Just press `Ctrl + s` (even if the file is unchanged) and click the run button again. It should trigger a signal for the Juno Workspace to display the variables.

This hack works for me on my Linux machine. It is a little bit slow but the Workspace displays the Julia variables. Please refer to the screenshot below:
[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your solution did work. Thanks. One observation. Initially I entered the command `y = 4` while the workspace window was closed and hit Shift+Enter. The value `4` appeared just to the left of the command in the editor. However, when I opened the workspace window there was nothing there. I went back to the line and hit Shift+Enter again and this time I saw the information on the workspace window. So it looks like only those commands Shift+Entered while the workspace window is open will appear in that window. Is that correct? Also, if I close the workspace window and reopen it it reopens empty.

Comment: @Soldalma You are right. Commands shift entered while the workspace window is open will appear but I can still see the all the variables on the workspace window even if I close the window and reopen it. In my case, workspace window will only loses variables if I explicitly click on the Stop Julia button.